# What does the notation $g\cdot\omega$ mean in Spivak's Calculus on manifolds?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-topology, differential-forms

In chapter $4$ (Integration on chains) of Spivak's *Calculus on manifolds* he says the following:

> If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable and $\omega$ be a $k$ form on $\mathbb{R}^m$  then
>   $f^*(g\cdot\omega)=(g\circ f)\cdot f^*(\omega)$.

He said nothing about the $g$.

I think $g : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable. Then I guess we define $g\cdot\omega:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \Lambda^k(\mathbb{R}^m)$
as

$$(g\cdot\omega)(p)(v_1,\cdots,v_k)=g(v_1)g(v_2)\cdots g(v_k)\omega(p)(v_1,\cdots,v_k).$$

I am sure this does not make much sense but this is what I can think of as of now.

Please let me know more about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\omega$ is a differential $k$-form and $g$ is a smooth real-valued function then $g\cdot\omega$ (or just $g\omega$) is a differential $k$-form with

$$(g\cdot\omega)(p)(v_1, \dots, v_k) = g(p)\omega(p)(v_1, \dots, v_k).$$

What you wrote doesn't make sense as $p \in \mathbb{R}^m$ while $v_1, \dots, v_k \in T_p\mathbb{R}^m$, so $g(v_1), \dots, g(v_k)$ are not defined as $v_1, \dots, v_k$ are not elements of the domain of $g$.

More generally, for any smooth manifold $M$, given a differential $k$-form $\omega \in \Omega^k(M)$ and smooth function $g \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$, $g\cdot\omega$ is again a differential $k$-form, defined as above. In fact, $\Omega^k(M)$ is a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$-module.

Comment: $v_1,v_2$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^m$ so $g(v_i)$ is defined i guess..

Comment: Not quite, $v_1, \dots, v_k$ are elements of $T_p\mathbb{R}^m$ which is not equal to $\mathbb{R}^m$, it is only isomorphic to it.

Comment: I am sorry but i missed your point... $g:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\omega:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \Lambda^k(\mathbb{R}^m)$.. $\omega(p):\mathbb{R}^m\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$... I do not understand where does that tanget space came from...

Comment: The $\mathbb{R}^m$'s in the map $\omega(p)$ are not the same as the $\mathbb{R}^m$ to which $p$ belongs. The $\mathbb{R}^m$'s in the map $\omega(p)$ are actually $T_pM$'s, Spivak must be implictly using the fact that $T_p\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ are isomorphic. You shouldn't think of $p$ and $v_1, \dots, v_k$ as being elements of the same space (because they're not). In the case of a manifold $M$, we have $p \in M$ and $v_1, \dots, v_k \in T_pM$ (**points** belong to the manifold, and **vectors** belong to the tangent space).

Comment: Ok Ok.. I have checked just now.. He says "... a function $\omega$ with $\omega(p)\in \Lambda^k(\mathbb{R}^n_p)$; such a function is called a k form on $\mathbb{R}^n$"... This $\mathbb{R}^n_p$ is the tangent space... I was wrong..

Comment: +1 for "points belongs to the manifold, and vectors belongs to the tangent space"... A very big punch on my face... Thanks... :D